# retrieve last two string of a query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I would like to be able to retrieve the last two string of a query. In the sense that I have an item known as course_tax that is retrieve as 1.05 or 1.10 or 1.11, etc. I would like to just retrieve 05,10, or 11.

this is essentially how I am retrieving it now:

```
$course_id = $_GET['crs_id'];
$get_crs = "select * from courses where course_id='$course_id'";
$run_crs = mysqli_query($con, $get_crs);

while($row_crs=mysqli_fetch_array($run_crs)){
    $course_tax = $row_crs['course_tax'];
}
```

Comment: Not sure about MySQL solution, but simple str_replace() could be solution for output, e.g.  $tax=str_replace('1.','',$course_tax);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem depends on two things:

1. If the value you are expecting from the database is always in this
   format: x.xx where x is an integer.
2. If you are not sure to what degree of precision the result is going
   to come out from the database.

If one is the case, this simple sql query should solve it:

`"SELECT *, right(course_tax, 2) as 'course_tax' FROM courses where course_id = '$course_id'";`

Else if two is the case, you have to use one of the functions available in php.
The most advisable to use is the `explode($delimiter, $haystack)` function. So this should definitely work:

`$exploded = explode(".", $row_crs['course_tax']);
$course_tax = $exploded[1];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to just get the decimal part of the number. Try using `explode` like this:

```
while($row_crs=mysqli_fetch_array($run_crs)){
    $dig = explode(".", $row_crs['course_tax']);
    $course_tax = $dig[1];
}
```